# How to get UIImage from pixels in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a point of picture in memory, but how do I get a UIImage?

I tried two methods below and use **"UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, nil, nil);"** to save the image to my album, but it didn't work. How do I solve this?

First:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:texture->data  length:picSize];
UIImage* myImage = [ [ UIImage alloc ]initWithData:imageData ];
```

Second:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, texture->data, texture->image_size.width * texture->image_size.height * texture->bytesPerPixel, NULL);
// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * 320;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(320, 480, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Comment: "Didn't work" - in what sense? What did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: I want to save it to my album. But it didn't work. I use " UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, nil, nil);"

Comment: What did image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: say ?

Comment: What the kind of data?

Comment: Looks like `myImage` is nil.